# How to create multiple barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to create multiple barplot. I can do it this way:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3 = axes.flat

ax0.hist(tweets["red"])
ax0.set_title('Red in backgrounds')

ax1.hist(tweets["red"][tweets["candidate"] == "trump"].values)
ax1.set_title('Red in Trump tweeters')

ax2.hist(tweets["blue"])
ax2.set_title('Blue in backgrounds')

ax3.hist(tweets["blue"][tweets["candidate"] == "trump"].values)
ax3.set_title('Blue in Trump tweeters')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But what if I have 10 variables or 16 variables? Should O manually create barplots?

Another option is to use `tweets.hist()`, but then the chart is very small and I cannot control its size.

Comment: What are you asking, What's the problem? Look up what [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) returns: the most important part probably being: `ax : Axes object or array of Axes objects.`. This can be indexed like `axes[i].hist()`. (ignored potential dimensions)

Comment: `dataframe.hist` has a `figsize` paramater that takes a tuple of (row, height) in inches.

Comment: @ScottBoston: yeah, indeed I solved it with `df.hist(figsize=(20,10))`. Thank you!